# Chessboard_ combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Suppose we have a chessboard of type $2j$ by $2j$ all of whose unit cells are of color white .

In every move , we may select $3$ consecutive cells belonging to either one row or one column and recolour them ( white becomes black and vice-versa ) .

Find all such $j$  for which we can reach a chess - board coloring after a finite number of moves . ( We let $j$ to be not less than $2$ )

Comment: anyone who can solve this ....

Comment: Okay  let's see how fast one solves it .

Comment: it seems that nobody can solve this problem ....

Comment: If you want help here, goading isn't likely to work.  Much better would be to add where you found the problem, what steps you have taken yourself to attempt solving it.

Comment: Even some simple context, such as nontrivial examples of $j$ for which a "checkered" coloring can be reached (or not reached), would be a welcome improvement.

Comment: Essentially duplicate of [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323245/flipping-coins-in-a-chessboard](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323245/flipping-coins-in-a-chessboard). The dimension of the board is more general but the idea is the same. For some boards (6x6) it is possible.